# Update Office Attribute Powershell

Tags: powershell, directory

```
Get-AdUser -filter "displayname -eq 'John Snow'" | Set-ADObject -Office "New Office"
```

How do I update a users 'Office' (physicalDeliveryOfficeName) in Powershell?

I've tried `-Replace` also with no luck.

Comment: [Read the docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-aduser?view=win10-ps)

Answer (score -1):

```
Get-AdUser -filter "displayname -eq 'John Snow'" | Set-ADUser -Office "New Office"
```